# How to add fill color to a 2D Graphics object?

Tags: graphics

Problem / background: consider the following code snippet.

```
pnt[fig_, n_] := {fig[[1, n]], fig[[2, n]]}
hor := {.025, .1, .25, .4, .475, .525, .6, .75, .9, .975}
ver := {.05, .20, .80, .95}
fig4 := Transpose[{
   {hor[[1]], ver[[2]], 1}, {hor[[2]], ver[[1]], 1}, {hor[[4]], 
    ver[[1]], 1}, {hor[[5]], ver[[2]], 1},
   {hor[[1]], ver[[3]], 1}, {hor[[2]], ver[[4]], 1}, {hor[[4]], 
    ver[[4]], 1}, {hor[[5]], ver[[3]], 1},
   {hor[[6]], ver[[2]], 1}, {hor[[7]], ver[[1]], 1}, {hor[[9]], 
    ver[[1]], 1}, {hor[[10]], ver[[2]], 1},
   {hor[[6]], ver[[3]], 1}, {hor[[7]], ver[[4]], 1}, {hor[[9]], 
    ver[[4]], 1}, {hor[[10]], ver[[3]], 1},
   {hor[[3]], ver[[2]], 1}, {hor[[3]], ver[[3]], 1},
   {hor[[8]], ver[[2]], 1}, {hor[[8]], ver[[3]], 1}
   }]
draw4A[fig_] := {
  BezierCurve[{pnt[fig, 1], pnt[fig, 2], pnt[fig, 3], pnt[fig, 4]}],
  BezierCurve[{pnt[fig, 5], pnt[fig, 6], pnt[fig, 7], pnt[fig, 8]}],
  BezierCurve[{pnt[fig, 9], pnt[fig, 10], pnt[fig, 11], pnt[fig, 12]}],
  BezierCurve[{pnt[fig, 13], pnt[fig, 14], pnt[fig, 15], 
    pnt[fig, 16]}],
  Line[{pnt[fig, 1], pnt[fig, 4]}],
  Line[{pnt[fig, 5], pnt[fig, 8]}],
  Line[{pnt[fig, 9], pnt[fig, 12]}],
  Line[{pnt[fig, 13], pnt[fig, 16]}]}
Graphics[draw4A[fig4]]
```

which draws four half-pie type of objects:

[image]

Question: I want to fill each part with a different, optional color different than that of the surrounding line. **How can I add this fill color?**

Comment: Question: for `hor`, `ver`, and `fig4` your using [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html), yet they're static values. Are these just place holders for more complex code, as plane `Set` is better in this context?

Comment: Thank you for noticing @rcollyer. I'll have look at it. The actual code does more than this though.

Comment: I figured it was more complex and they were possibly acting as placeholders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are looking for [FilledCurve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like it..., am going to try this now,.

Comment: Yes, works much easier than expected, thank you. - http://mathematics-diary.blogspot.com/2012/02/drawing-friezes-with-bezier-curves-2.html

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can use `FaceForm` if you want to specify more than one directive (i.e. not just color, but opacity, etc.) for the primitive:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[.2]}], EdgeForm[Black], 
  FilledCurve[BezierCurve[{{-1, 0}, {-1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}}]]}, 
 ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I gave this a vote, but now I am wondering is it necessary to use both FaceForm and EdgeForm?  Can you not simply give the directives in FaceForm directly?  This appears to work with other primitives.  Is FilledCurve different?

Comment: I think you need both as they cannot be combined. For example you cannot specify `Thickness` in `FaceForm`, as it results in the Pink Screen of Death.

Comment: But are there any combinations that require both `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm`?  You could put Thickness in either the main list or `EdgeForm`, right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I could not think of any at the moment. Proper order of naked directives in the main list usually is enough. Would be nice to find a counterexample though.